# Cannot resolve file qcar_config.xsd with Vuforia

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have code set up with vuforia that utilizes four vision targets with Vuforia. This code enables the robot to tell its distance relative to other objects. I have the following code for the .xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <QCARConfig xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="qcar_config.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
   <Tracking>
    <ImageTarget name="gears" size="0.279400 0.215900" />
    <ImageTarget name="legos" size="0.279400 0.215900" />
    <ImageTarget name="tools" size="0.279400 0.215900" />
    <ImageTarget name="wheels" size="0.279400 0.215900" />
    </Tracking>
 </QCARConfig>
```

The qcar_config.xsd text turns red, and I get the error "Cannot resolve file qcar_config.xsd" I've spent a long time looking for solutions on the internet, and was not able to find any. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this the FULL file as you saved it? If yes... the </QCARConfig is not closed.....

Comment: The > brace is in the code on my computer, forgot to include it in this post @Layna. That was not the full code in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem solved on Vuforia Forum:

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/qcar-api/problem-qcarconfig

> "t's not an issue if the XML schema is missing and the project will
>   compile just fine, but if you just want to make Android Studio remove
>   red highlighting, create an empty file called qcar_config.xsd. You can
>   read up on XML schema format here if you want more info:
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp"

So, don't worry, it's not a problem.